# Xcode 8 Beta (null) was unable to service the request

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10

I have an app that worked fine in the released version of Xcode. I downloaded the beta and after I fixed all the little changes I ran it and it worked. I just came back and ran it again and I get an error saying

> The request to open "com.matthewhsingleton.Smoke" failed .   (null) was unable to service the request.

[image]

I have quit Xcode and reopened it, I have restarted my computer, tried different iPhone simulators and all produce the same resulte

Comment: Join [the discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143094#143094) on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: None of these were working for me... So I decided to change the simulator from iPhone 7 to iPhone 6... It worked!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After reading @Droppy suggestion I read the thread and it is a common issue. To solve it is as follows

> Problem solved for by an Apple Engineer in the lab. It's an issue they're working on. The bottom line was that when I copied Xcode to Applications folder, there was a bit set on it and that was preventing it from communicating with the simulator.
>
> To fix it:
>   Copy-paste Xcode-beta.app from Applications folder to somewhere else, e.g. Documents folder.
>   Delete Xcode-beta.app from Applications folder.
>   Move Xcode-beta.app from Documents to Applications folder again.

Seen here https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143094#143094

Comment: The answer is at the very bottom (as of this posting)

Comment: Also this solved the error of Playground: 'the file “playground.xcworkspace” doesn’t exist'. Thanks.

Comment: This is the weirdest, most voodoo fix I have seen in a long time. Maybe ever.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I hope they fix it soon. Or perhaps something else could also cause this...?

Answer (score 20):

My error was similar, instead of "(null)", the message was: "SpringBoard was unable to service the request"

Restarting the simulator worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had 2 versions of Xcode installed. Xcode 7 and 8. I resolved this issue by setting the command line tools to Xcode 8 in preferences. Open preferences -> Locations -> Command Line tools. Set that to Xcode 8.