# Xcode 8 beta LLDB keeps crashing

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Whenever I try and print something in the debugger, it will crash and deliver this line

"The LLDB RPC server has crashed. Please file a bug with Apple with the crash log."

Comment: Following the steps in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827635/xcode-8-beta-null-was-unable-to-service-the-request has seemed to resolve the problem. I'm not sure if the two are related or if I did something else to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

LLDB is being run in a separate process now so if the debugger crashes, it no longer will crash Xcode, it will just crash the lldb-rpc-server and post this message. If you can file a bug with repro steps and hopefully source code and attach the crash log for lldb-rpc-server to the bug, we can figure things out.

I would recommend going a clean + rebuild to ensure that everything is rebuilt with the new compilers and so the modules get updated. If you are using CocoaPods or Carthage, then be sure to update any of those projects to the latest and greatest and clean and rebuild them.