# XCode 8: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Created a new project on XCode 8, installed 1 pod that is of `Alamofire` and then checked my app if everything is ok, it ran well. And then I hooked up a `tableView` in the interface builder as I would previously do in earlier versions of XCode, defined the classes, connected the tableviewCell and when I run, the app crashed on my iPhone 5s, being used as my test device. Moreover, there is no error line that I could encounter or shown to the console. Also, I have not force unwrapped any optional. The code crashes before it could reach `viewDidLoad()` method in the starting viewController.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as defined as voodoo in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37828105/3921490, but will give a try if conventional approach doesn't work.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to narrow down the place where the error occurs.

Comment: Can you specify in code with debugging where the problem occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

Set identifier in the Storyboard/xib of the Custom Cell like below:

[image]

Use same identifier in tableView delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as TableViewCell

        //related code here
}
```

Comment: Thats right but you cant access your cells properties like Label, Try to access label of your cell in tableview delegate method. I have posted same question